# Batch - if (file) exist command?

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm trying to write some lines of Batch code, that should check if there are files (no directories) in a directory.

Here is my code:

```
if exist a*.* ( 
echo Es wurden Dateien die mit A beginnen gefunden
echo.
>>%protokoll%.txt echo Es wurden Dateien die mit A beginnen gefunden
set "gefunden=true"
>>%protokoll%.txt echo.
)
```

My problem is that the if a*.* (That checks if there are any files or directories that start with an a) also returns true when there is a directory that starts with an a. But I don't want that. 
How can I check if there are files that start with an a, but it should not return true if there is only a firectory/folder that starts with an a.

I hope you understand what I mean, and of course I've already tried the search function but I wasn't able to find something that solves my problems.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dir /a-d a* >nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo file not found) else (echo file found)
```

should detect files-only.